# How to determine whether a value exists in map in C++

Tags: c++, stl, hashtable

I understand that std::map is (Key, Value) pairs.

I want to search through the values of a map. Let us say that I want to find the highest value among the values in the std::map. How can I do that ?
For example let me consider a map like this:

> John    -> 100
>
> Jeffrey  -> 200
>
> Krishna -> 147

I think it will be similar to this , but I am  not sure.

```
 for (auto it=m.begin(); it!=m.end(); it++)
    { 
       if (it->second == 500)
          { 
             cout << "Found"; 
          }
        else { 
             continue;}
   }
```

Instead of iterating through std::map, is there any other inbuilt method using which I can check if a value exists in a std::map with ***O(1)*** time complexity ?

Comment: well, yes :) that's it

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: are you actually searching for the max or a random value?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

Comment: First you say map then you say hashmap - they are different make your mind

Comment: It´s better to have two maps (key->value and value->key) if you need to find the value frequently.

Comment: @Slava Thanks for letting me know about it. I thought both were same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: How to check if a value exists in hashmap?

You need to iterate through and check if such item exists. You can use [`std::find_if()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a lambda or do that through a loop. If you do that quite often you may want to index values as well (see below)

> Q2: How to iterate through all the values in a map and find the largest value or the smallest value ?

Again you iterate through container and find it or you can use [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) or [`std::min_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) with a lambda as well. Though if you need to access values in sorted order you may consider to use [`boost::multimap`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost/container/multimap.html) which will allow to access data using hashed index by name and provide sorted or hashed index(es) for values, though you should be aware of a price of every index added.

Answer (score 1):

For the second question, use:

```
std::map<std::string, int> foo = {{"John",100},{"Jeffrey",200},{"Krishna",147}};
std::cout << std::max_element(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](const auto& p1, const auto& p2){return p1.second < p2.second;})->first;
std::cout << std::min_element(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](const auto& p1, const auto& p2){return p1.second < p2.second;})->first;
```

Use an adapted lambda with `std::find_if`, you should be able to find also if a value exists in a map (or hash table).